# Automated generation of homework questions for line problems

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, string-manipulation

I try to help my children in their subjects, I built a small code so that it has as output questions regarding the equation of the line, but I have not been able to modify it so that the result comes out randomly a) parallel b) perpendicular
and the other thing I get the minus sign to come out randomly but when it is +, I don't know how to write it and it comes out + -, would you be so kind to help me improve the code and maybe the numbered exercises come out
Thanks in advance

```
a := RandomInteger[{1, 10}];
b := RandomInteger[{1, 10}];
c := RandomInteger[{1, 10}];
(*ax+by+c=0*)
(*dx+ ey+f=0*)

d := RandomInteger[{1, 10}];
e := RandomInteger[{1, 10}];
f := RandomInteger[{1, 10}];
g := RandomInteger[{0, 1}];
Table [Print [" Find 'k' so that the line " , (-1)^(g + 1)*a, 
"x+", (-1)^(g + 1)*b, "y+" , (-1)^(g + 1)*c  , 
"=0 be perpendicular/parallel to the line"  , (-1)^(g + 1)*d, 
 "x+(", ((-1)^(g + 1)*e), "+k)y+" , (-1)^(g + 1)*f , "=0 " ], {i, 1, 
 20}]
```

Comment: For the issue of **comes out + -,** this needs addition check, since you have hardocded `x+` in there and the random number sometimes comes negative with `-` in it already. So you need to add an extra check to  only use `+` when the random number is positive and not negative so not to get the double sign.  I can add this later. Just need to make some coffee now first.

Comment: fyi, added the check for the +- issue.

Comment: Not related to the code but as someone that started loving mathematics after I started understanding it in university, I think I would have seriously hated math if I had to use the same method 20 times or even more than 5 times maybe. My guess is less than 3 maybe 4  is enough if the concepts and mechanisms are understood. Also my guess is that being stuck in straight forward procedures  could lower imagination or gives false ideas as to what solving math problems is like at a higher level. In principle I probably should not give my personal opinion but it was hard for me to not write this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be

```
a := RandomInteger[{1, 10}];
b := RandomInteger[{1, 10}];
c := RandomInteger[{1, 10}];
(*ax+by+c=0*)
(*dx+ey+f=0*)

d := RandomInteger[{1, 10}];
e := RandomInteger[{1, 10}];
f := RandomInteger[{1, 10}];
g := RandomInteger[{0, 1}];
```

And now

```
data = Reap@Table[
    z0 = (-1)^(g + 1)*a;
    z1 = (-1)^(g + 1)*b;
    z2 = (-1)^(g + 1)*c;
    z3 = ((-1)^(g + 1)*e);
    z4 = (-1)^(g + 1)*f;
    z5 = (-1)^(g + 1)*d;
    
    sign1 = If[z1 < 0, "", "+"];
    sign2 = If[z2 < 0, "", "+"];
    sign3 = If[z3 < 0, "-", "+"];
    sign4 = If[z4 < 0, "", "+"];
    Which[z0 == 1, z0 = "", z0 == -1, z0 = "-"];
    Which[z1 == 1, z1 = "", z1 == -1, z1 = "-"];
    Which[z5 == 1, z5 = "", z5 == -1, z5 = "-"];
    
    par = If[RandomInteger[{0, 1}] == 1, "parallel", "perpendicular"];
    Sow[{i, 
      Row[{" Find 'k' so that the line ", z0, "x ", sign1, z1, "y ", 
        sign2, z2, " = 0 be ", par, " to the line ", z5, "x ", sign3, 
        "(", z3, "+k)y ", sign4, z4, "=0 "}]}], {i, 1, 20}];

Grid[data[[1]], Frame -> All, Alignment -> Left, 
 FrameStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image]

ps. too much HW's for your kids. Take it easy on them :)

Comment: ,thanks for the answers, ha ha that's the math they see in high school, could you add the random alternation of the words "parallel" and "perpendicular" to the code and if possible the numbering of the exercises in the form 01,02, 03 .....10,11,12....(only if it can appear x and not 1x) in advance very grateful

Comment: I run it in MMA 13 and it does not display anything ????

Comment: thanks,is missing a "hair"
in exercises 4 and 5 and others at the end it continues to appear + - could you add what is missing if I like what I asked you for x to appear and not 1x, -x and not -1x

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, I was reviewing your spreadsheet and looking at exercises 8,9,14,18... there is a small mistake
in 8, for example, it should say 6x at the beginning and not 6+x, in the others it is similar and a sign is missing in between

Comment: It's perfect, thank you very much, just one detail, when executing it appears in a row
  
sign1=+z1=8 sign2=z2=-4

sign1= z1=-1 sign2=+ z2=7
.......

I don't know how to remove it, it doesn't affect the result but it's a bit annoying

Comment: Can you try the update I just posted now (version 50 :) ? You should not see any `sign` anything in the output.

Comment: Thank you for everything, it turned out very well and I learned many things in the process, thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

I didn't want to deal with expression ordering, but how could I forget that Mathematica formats equations by default!

```
Clear[a, s1, s2]
a := RandomChoice[Range[-10, -1]~Join~Range[1, 10]]
s1 := ToString@ (a x + a y) <> " " <> 
  ToString@NumberForm[a, NumberSigns -> {"-", "+"}] <> " = 0"
s2 := ToString@ (a x + (a + k) y) <> " " <> 
  ToString@NumberForm[a, NumberSigns -> {"-", "+"}] <> " = 0"
Table[
  {StringPadLeft[#, 2] &@ToString@i, 
   StringForm["Find 'k' so that the line `` be `` to the line ``.",
    s1, pp, s2]
   },
  {i, 10}
  ] // TableForm
```

[image]

---

**Original**

```
a := RandomChoice[Range[-10, -1]~Join~Range[1, 10]]
pp := RandomChoice[{"perpendicular", "parallel"}]
cfull := ToString@NumberForm[a, NumberSigns -> {"-", "+"}];
cmid := With [{a = a}, 
  If[a == -1, "-", 
   If[a == +1, "+", 
    If[a > 1 || a < -1, 
     ToString@NumberForm[a, NumberSigns -> {"-", "+"}]]
    ]]]
cfront := 
 With [{a = a}, 
  If[a == -1, "-", If[a == +1, "+", ToString@NumberForm[a]]
   ]]
cbracket := 
 With [{a = a}, 
  If[a == -1, "-1", 
   If[a == +1, "1", ToString@NumberForm[a, NumberSigns -> {"-", "+"}]]]
  ]
Table[
  {StringPadLeft[#, 2] &@ToString@i, 
   StringForm[
    "Find 'k' so that the line ``x ``y `` = 0 be `` to the line ``x \
+(``+k)y `` = 0.",
    cfront, cmid, cfull, pp, cfront, cbracket, cfull
    ]},
  {i, 10}
  ] // TableForm
```

[image]